# lazy instantiation and instance lifetimes in POM

Tags: c#

I've been considering the pro's and con's between implementing my page objects with privately backed properties and lazily instantiating them or just returning new instances every time and am curious what other people think is the best practice.

For example, I could have something like;

```
    private IWebElement title = null;
    public IWebElement Title
    {
        get
        {
            if (title == null)
                title = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("Title"));
            return title;
        }
    }
```

To represent a button on the page, or I could just have;

```
   public IWebElement Title { get { _driver.FindElement(By.Id("Title")); } }
```

Which method do you think is better and why?

Comment: Can you explain why this is considered too opinion based? You could easily provide data to support a design decision and it's codereview... is there any code review that isn't opinion based? I spent quite awhile last night looking for blog posts/papers that provided some data to support the differences between these approaches but couldn't find anything, based on that this seemed like the best place to ask.

Comment: In our [about] page, it says the following: Don't ask about: Best practices in general (that is, it's okay to ask "Does this code follow common best practices?", but not "What is the best practice regarding X?")

Comment: Also, you ask about "what other people **think** is the **best practice**" and "Which method do you **think** is better and **why?**". Basically, it all depends on which parameters you consider for something to be "best practice". You are right that code review is often opinion based, but this question is *primarily* opinion based. You're asking "Which is best, A or B?" and generally such questions are not well appreciated around here.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg this is a code review site, code reviews are inherently opinion based... The examples in your about are just people posting their opinions about how to implement something. This community is even more pretentious than SO's which is saying a lot.

Comment: If you really feel so, please start a question on our [meta] to discuss the on-topicness off this question.

Comment: Yes, this sounds opinion-based.  It's also not really asking for a code review, just a comparison of two example code snippets.  This question may be better for Programmers, which deals with best practices in general.  You should also revise the question to request credible info instead of opinions.

Answer (score 1):

That all really depends on one thing and one thing only:

**How costly** is the `_driver.FindElement(By.Id("Title"));` operation?

Secondly... OK then, maybe two things: **How often** do you plan on calling this method?

If the operation is cheap, I would use the return directly version.
 If the operation is costly, use the approach with the variable.

Additionally, if this is a multi-threaded environment - or rather, *when* this possibly becomes a multi-threaded environment - the first approach goes out the window unless you synchronize on some lock (which will add some additional overhead). The first approach as it looks today is not thread safe at all.

Comment: I would add that the variable approach, as shown, has no thread-safety.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer Good thinking, added that.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg aside from the thread safety points that's the main trade off I've been considering. I was hoping someone would provide something more concrete like a nice little table with data for various scenarios, something I can actually make an educated guess with... Perhaps I'll have to do it myself.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal As we don't have the same computer, the same code, the same anything. You really should do it yourself.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Remember though that if you make some code to compare the different scenarios, we'd gladly review that code to see if you can make it more flexible and prettier :)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I disagree that not using my hardware, code ect is necessary. I can't find anywhere on the internet some ballpark numbers to get started with. The performance of find by id on a page with a given content length is not going to vary with everything else held the same. Simply a comparison of xpath look ups vs by id look ups would be extremely useful and isn't readily available online.